# How to perform Boolean operations in mesh in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, csg

I have `Cube` model and `Cylinder` model. I want to make a hole inside `Cube` by `Cylinder`, how can I make it?

I have these two models:

[image]

And I want to make this:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is *Boolean Operations on Mesh*.

Use [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/boolean-subtraction-operations-on-mesh.85713/) thread to learn more about it.

Here is repository from [GitHub](https://github.com/karl-/pb_CSG). Which was previously used a lot, still can be used. Want to know more, use [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1425100/java-script-option-is-missing-from-the-create-menu.html) thread.

And if you are in a hassle, here is a [repo](https://github.com/KaimaChen/MeshBoolean). I have used it.